# Unresolved external symbol vftable c++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc, vtk

I am using visual studio 2008 in my MFC + vtk project. There I am getting a linking error as below:

> vtkPBFEAView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ?DrawDC@vtkMFCWindow@@QAEXPAVCDC@@@Z (public: void __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::DrawDC(class CDC *)) imported in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall CvtkPBFEAView::OnDraw(class CDC *)" (?OnDraw@CvtkPBFEAView@@MAEXPAVCDC@@@Z)
>
> 1>vtkMDIView.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ?DrawDC@vtkMFCWindow@@QAEXPAVCDC@@@Z (public: void __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::DrawDC(class CDC *)) imported
>   1>vtkPBFEAView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??0vtkMFCWindow@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z (public: __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::vtkMFCWindow(class CWnd *)) imported in function "public: void __thiscall vtkPBFEAViewImpl::initialize(class CWnd *)" (?initialize@vtkPBFEAViewImpl@@QAEXPAVCWnd@@@Z)
>
> 1>vtkMDIView.obj : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol ??0vtkMFCWindow@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z (public: __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::vtkMFCWindow(class CWnd *)) imported
>   1>vtkPBFEAView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1vtkMFCWindow@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::~vtkMFCWindow(void)) imported in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GvtkMFCWindow@@UAEPAXI@Z)
>
> 1>vtkMDIView.obj : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol ??1vtkMFCWindow@@UAE@XZ (public: virtual __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::~vtkMFCWindow(void)) imported in function "public: void __thiscall vtkMDIViewImpl::adjust_contours(int,double,double)" (?adjust_contours@vtkMDIViewImpl@@QAEXHNN@Z)
>
> 1>vtkMFCWindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_*declspec(dllimport) const vtkMFCWindow::`vftable'" (*_imp_??_7vtkMFCWindow@@6B@) referenced in function "public: __thiscall vtkMFCWindow::vtkMFCWindow(class CWnd *)" (??0vtkMFCWindow@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@@Z)

Can anyone explain me the reason for this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a similar question [asked here](http://vtk.1045678.n5.nabble.com/Build-from-GIT-Master-Linker-errors-td5429952.html), see if it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the link @satuon. I am building vtk with dll files now but it has udes static libs earlier. May be this is the problem, so I am trying to build vtk with static libs, which I found dificult to build earlier. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks again.

Comment: In the link I gave the solution was to build with shared libraries instead of static libs (they turn on BUILD_SHARED_LIBS). Did you do that?

Comment: Yes.I am using SHARED_LIBS option and I am linking all the libraries.

Comment: So, are you building with shared libraries now, or with static libraries? I'm asking because you said earlier "so I am trying to build vtk with static libs".

Comment: Yes. I am now building shared libs. But getting the same error plus another two linking errors as below:            >cad.lib(postprocess_mg.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: class vtkCellData * __thiscall vtkDataSet::GetCellData(void)" (?GetCellData@vtkDataSet@@QAEPAVvtkCellData@@XZ) already defined in vtkFiltering.lib(vtkFiltering.dll)
1>cad.lib(postprocess_mg.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: class vtkPointData * __thiscall vtkDataSet::GetPointData(void)" (?GetPointData@vtkDataSet@@QAEPAVvtkPointData@@XZ) already defined in vtkFiltering.lib(vtkFiltering.dll)

Comment: It looks like you have multiple definition of the same function. You should remove the static libs from the build script.

Comment: Hi @satuon, build script is the .vcproj file, isn't it? I removed vtk libs from it in debug version only. Still getting the error. :(

Comment: I removed vtk libs, which removed the linking errors. but then the exe file is not created. Please help me.

Comment: Which error are you getting? Is it the same LNK2005, or different?

Comment: I am not getting any error now when building. But when I try to start the program it complains that it can't find the exe file. The exe file is not created in the debug folder.

Comment: Hi @satuon, I removed static libs from the build script. But still I am getting the same linking errors. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for the problem. It was that vtkMFCWindow was configured with /MD option and my main project was configured with /MTd option. And therefore I got the error. Once I removed the  **__declspec( dllexport )** lines and it worked well.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that might find this solution and be upset that their DLL Function is no longer exported to be used by the client app:

MSVC's DLL template provides the following bit of boilerplate:

```
#ifdef DLLNAME_EXPORTS
  #define DLLNAME_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
  #define DLLNAME_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

If you forget to define the DLLNAME_EXPORTS in the project settings, you'll get this message. This can happen if you rename these #defines